# Array inside document wont $push, $pull, and $inc $each

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection where each document is formatted:

```
{
  "_id": "57e81e0d5891000c99cc133b",
  "name": "service_name",
  "use": 8,
  "errors": [],
}
```

`errors` could be full of objects like:

```
{
  "e": {
    "error": "socket hang up"
  },
  "d": "2016-10-02T18:14:27.040Z",
  "n":1
},
{
  "e": {
    "error": "no data"
  },
  "d": "2016-10-02T18:22:15.257Z",
  "n":2
},
{
  "e": {
    "error": "because derp"
  },
  "d": "2016-10-02T19:55:09.588Z",
  "n":3
}
```

### What I am trying to do

I want to try a web based service and when the service produces an error I am to save it along with `n=0`, increment `use` (for the times I have called that service) and then iterate through all errors incrementing `errors.n+=1`. if any errors.n > 100 delete it!

---

Originally I tried to combine both queries into one (both $pull and $push on the same document array will produce the error Cannot update 'field1' and 'field1' at the same time)

So then I tried:

```
var error='something went boom';

db.collection('quota').update({name:'service'},{$pull:{errors:{$gt:{['errors.n']:100}}}},function(e,r){              
    db.collection('quota').update(
        {name:'service'},
        {$inc:{use:1}},
        {$push:{errors:{e:error,n:0}}},
    function(e,r){'done';});
```

Only the inc on `use` happens (from what I remember I sometimes got an error item pushed but the behavior was totally inconstant and the $pull never happens)

---

So I separated all the commands but still only inc `use happens`

```
db.collection('quota').update({name:'service'},{$pull:{errors:{$gt:{['errors.n']:100}}}},function(e,r){
    console.dir([1,e]);
    db.collection('quota').update({name:'service'},{$inc:{use:1}},function(e,r){
        console.dir([2,e]);
        db.collection('quota').update({name:'service'},{$push:{errors:{e:d.error,n:0,x:'x'}}},function(e,r){
            console.dir([3,e]);
                 db.collection('quota').update({'errors.x':'x'},{$inc:{'errors.$.n':1}},function(e,r){
                    console.dir([4,e]);
                    //done
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

(all errors are null)

Why for the love of god? I'm going mental!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
var error='something went boom';

db.collection('quota').update({name:'service'},{$pull:{'errors':{n : {$gt: 100}}}},function(e,r){              
    db.collection('quota').update(
        {name:'service'},
        {$push:{errors:{e:error,n:0}}, $inc:{use:1}},
    function(e,r){'done';});
```

You are passing $push as an third argument which is for options.

**Alternate:**

```
 db.collection('quota').update({name:'service'},{$pull:{'errors':{n : {$gt: 100}}}},{new: true},function(e,r){ 
      if(e) return next(e);
      r.errors.push({e:error,n:0});
      r.save();
})
```